# Ver codigo fuente html, seguridad

Tags: html, seguridad

Tengo en mi código `html` esta instrucción:

`style="display:none;`

El problema es que desde la inspección de código fuente pueden modificarlo y así poder ver el `div` en el que se encuentra la instrucción.

¿Hay alguna forma para que no puedan modificar esto?

Comment: Intenta redireccionarlo a un index.html o php que tenga solo el mensaje de redireccionamiento

Comment: Lo que podrías intentar, no lo he hecho, es con javascript ir verificando que no cambie el display, en el caso de que se pueda hacer, siempre que se modifique podrías hacer que se recargue la página y listo(?

Comment: si lo quieren modificar lo van a modificar, replantear la seguridad. no todo acceso es por navegador visual. un bot va a ver el código, si hay algo sensible ahí hay muchas posibilidades de terminar en un resultado de google

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente, una vez que la información es presentada en la interfaz (ya sea en elementos visibles o no visibles), no hay forma de controlar lo que un usuario hará con ella. Si es información confidencial o restringida, lo mejor es que:

1. No la mostrés; o
2. La mostrés cifrada o ilegible, de forma que solamente la aplicación pueda usar la información que estás mostrando.

Recordá que ningún método de ocultar información que es accesible a la interfaz es del todo confiable, ya que con un poco de interacción con la consola, se puede acceder a cualquier información que ya fue mostrada en la página.

Las validaciones para los valores que no querés que se modifiquen en la interfaz deben estar a nivel del controlador (o quien vaya a recibir el contenido que querés mantener íntegro).

Answer (score 1):

Ocultar cosas en el html da una falsa sensación de seguridad, no hace falta consola para descubrirlas.

Desde un marcador (bookmark/favorito) podes ejecutar javascript en el contexto de la página actual.

En este caso busco los divs y les pongo `display block`, podes cambiar el color del texto /fondo etc...

Algo mas elaborado sería tomar info y enviarla a un servidor con el cors promiscuo para análisis posterior, recorrer el DOM y recrearlo en un div fixed para ver todas las clases y contenidos, etc...

Para crear un marcador con javascript le pones `javascript:` como protocolo en la url, o arrastrando un enlace que ya tenga la url armada a la barra de marcadores/favoritos.

Darle ejecutar al snippet y arrastrar el link a la barra de marcadores para futuros usos. (ojo que rompe visualmente todo el layout).

```html
<a href="javascript:(function(){document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((d)=>d.style.display='block')})();">averche</a>

<div style="display:none">no me veeen</div>
```

Esto es un ejemplo básico, un atacante mas profesional armaría una extensión de navegador.

Así que mi consejo es... replantear el esquema de seguridad.

Comment: Excelente aporte